# How Can I Create 3 Columns on a Webpage Using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I’m relatively new to webd and want to use bootstrap or any other CSS frameworks which exactly creates these 3three columns and display them, I’ve tried using a circle for images but can’t figure out the exact CSS to implement this if somebody can help me out with this would be great I’ve spent an entire night but can’t make it exactly look like this!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using grid system to divide something into 3 separate columns.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Hi, I’m fairly new and I don’t have the technical know how how to use the grid system, if you could write code that looks like this would be of huge help! I’ve tried copy pasting it doesn't look like this

Comment: I know how to use bootstrap buttons, making it inside a column like this with small round image inside with exact css i can’t wrap my head around it as i have just started learning html basics yesterday.

Comment: Make a `div` with `class="row"` which holds 3 `div` with `class="col"` and in every of this col divs you can put your round images.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create 3 columns with bootstrap first of all you have to import the bootstrap to your html. Than you need to create a row that contains your columns, and inside you can create the columns:

first column content
    
    
       second column content
    
    
       third column content

Comment: Hi, I’ve already added those files my bootstrap is working, I want the same exact 3 columns along with round images, can you help me design that? I can’t figure it out using bootstrap bg-ml col etc are confusing and new terms for me

Comment: create a row:
<div class="row>

Comment: inside a row you create three columns:
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4> content column 1</div>
<div class="col-4> content column 1</div>
<div class="col-4> content column 1</div>
</div>

Comment: Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. So, if you want three equal-width columns across, you can use .col-4.
Inside the content if you want a rounded image just add the <img class="rounded" src="link of your image"> 
Now you should see 3 columns with rounded image.
do you want to see the borders of your columns? Create your custom class with border (for example border: 1px solid black;) and you will see the borders of your 3 columns.